# Submit button taking me to link that states HTTP ERROR 405. How do I prevent this, so i can allow it to work the way it is intended to?

Tags: javascript, html, http, web, button

- I'm still learning, so if there's any help, or the answer is really trivial like something I need to put before hand, an explanation of the reason why  this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

This has been a problem ever since I have started using it for weekend projects. Whenever I make a button, for example one that I have been trying to use is

```
  <button type="submit" id="btn"  onclick="validate()">login</button>
```

However, when I click on the button, instead of showing me what its supposed to show, it just states this on a gray page.

This page isn’t working
If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405

HTML

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <form class="box"  method="post">
      <h3>login</h3>

      <div class="username">
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter username" id="username" name="usernmame" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="password">
        <input type="password" placeholder="enter password" id="password"">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="btn"  onclick="validate()">login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

JS
*//I do understand that this is not a good way of setting up a username and password ,since anyone can easily get it. Ive been just doing this as a weekend project, i just want it to show an alert if it works or not*

```
function validate(){
  let username = document.getElementById('username');
  value;
  let password=document.getElementById('password');
  value;

  if(username =='please' && password == 'work')
  {
    alert('finally');
  } else{
    alert("NOOOO")
  }
}
```

I have tried to see if it was a problem with my js, but nothing seems to change, so that is why im starting to suspect that it its the button thats causin the problem

Comment: submitting that form  (which will happen when you click submit button) will make a POST request to the current URL (since you have no `action` property on the `form`) HTTP 405 error is that the method (in this case) is not allowed - so, unless your server allows a POST on whatever URL you are currently viewing, the error is correct

Answer (score 0):

Firstly its not

```
document.getElementById('password');
  value;
```

its

```
document.getElementById('password').value;
```

Secondly, there is no action property present I'll suggest removing the entire form tags

```
<div class="wrapper">
          <h3>login</h3>
        
          <div class="username">
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter username" id="username" name="usernmame" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="password">
            <input type="password" placeholder="enter password" id="password"">
          </div>
          <button type=" submit" id="btn" onclick="validate()">login</button>
          </div>
        
          <script>
            function validate() {
              let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
              let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        
              if (username == 'please' && password == 'work') {
                alert('finally');
              } else {
                alert("NOOOO")
              }
            }
        
          </script>
```

Comment: tysm, it works now ! been thinking about this all day, thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

on your for, you are using attibute `method="post"` which has alternative of `method="get"` which being sent using URLs you are using `method="post"`  which has a missing attribute `action="/action_page.php"` that will process you're page.
Like this

```
<form class="box" action="/action_page.php" method="post">
```

since you don't have action attribute, and has method="post", the post is being sent to the same page you are sending and without receiving it properly like in php.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

If you still want to continue using javascript at test it, remove at post method, and remove the type="submit" on your button as it behaves on submitting if  you just want to test using javascript.

Here is your final script.

HTML

```
<form class="box">
      <h3>login</h3>

      <div class="username">
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter username" id="username" name="usernmame" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="password">
        <input type="password" placeholder="enter password" id="password"">
      </div>
      <button id="btn" onclick="validate()">login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

JS

```
function validate(){
  let username = document.getElementById('username').value;

  let password=document.getElementById('password').value;
 

  if(username =='please' && password == 'work')
  {
    alert('finally');
  } else{
    alert("NOOOO")
  }
}
```